# Client side rendering

Tags: .net, reactjs, client-server, client-side

In a server side (.net app) application, only the relevant page is loaded to the client. but in Client-Server (ReactJS + WebService) applications all pages are loaded on the client side. Do not initial loads cause performance loss?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean you cannot use "server pages" in React app for different parts of your application.

If it is a big app you can split the client code to several files. For example ,if you're using webpack you can use it's [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) feature.

Comment: do you have different approaches except this one?